# Displaying combined webcam feed on multiple devices using sockets and OpenCV

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, opencv, sockets

I have two devices, A and B, each with a webcam, and I want to display the combined feed from both webcams on both devices simultaneously. To achieve this, I am using sockets, OpenCV, and numpy in my implementation.

On `Device A`, I have the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import socket
import threading

# Receiver IP and port (Device B)
receiver_ip = '10.10.0.100'
receiver_port = 1234

# Sender IP and port (Device A)
sender_ip = '10.10.0.105'
sender_port = 5678

# Create a UDP socket for receiving data
receiver_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
receiver_socket.bind((receiver_ip, receiver_port))

# Create a UDP socket for sending data
sender_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

frame = np.zeros([800, 800], dtype=np.float32)
res1 = np.zeros([800, 800], dtype=np.float32)

# Function to receive and display frames from Device A
def receive_frames():
    global frame
    while True:
        data, address = receiver_socket.recvfrom(65535)

        # Convert the received data to a numpy array
        nparr = np.frombuffer(data, np.uint8)

        # Decode the numpy array into a frame
        frame = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

        cv2.imshow("Device A Frame", frame)
        
        # Break the loop if 'q' is pressed
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    # Close the receiver socket and destroy the receiver window
    receiver_socket.close()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Start a separate thread to receive frames from Device A
receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive_frames)
receive_thread.start()

# Initialize the video capture from the local camera (Device B)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def send_frames():
    global res1
    while True:
        # Read a frame from the local camera
        ret, cam1 = cap.read()
        
        if ret:
            # Resize the frame from the local camera
            res1 = cv2.resize(cam1, (800, 800))
            
            # Combine the resized frame from the local camera and the received frame from Device A
            dst = cv2.addWeighted(res1.astype(np.float32), 0.5, frame.astype(np.float32), 0.5, 0.0)
            
            # Encode the combined frame as JPEG
            ret, encoded_frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', dst, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 10])
            
            # Send the encoded frame to Device A
            sender_socket.sendto(encoded_frame.tobytes(), (sender_ip, sender_port))

            cv2.imshow("Combined Frame", dst)
            
        # Break the loop if 'q' is pressed
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    # Release the video capture object and close the sender socket
    cap.release()
    sender_socket.close()

# Start a separate thread to send frames to Device A
send_thread = threading.Thread(target=send_frames)
send_thread.start()

receive_thread.join()
send_thread.join()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

On `Device B`, I have the following code:

```
import cv2
import socket
import numpy as np
import threading

# Sender IP and port
sender_ip = '10.10.0.100'
sender_port = 1234

# Receiver IP and port
receiver_ip = '10.10.0.105'
receiver_port = 5678

# Create a UDP socket for sending data
sender_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Create a UDP socket for receiving data
receiver_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
receiver_socket.bind((receiver_ip, receiver_port))


def send_frames():
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        ret_val, frame = video_capture.read()
        # Convert the frame to a string
        ret, encoded_frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 10])

        # Send the frame to the sender
        sender_socket.sendto(encoded_frame.tobytes(), (sender_ip, sender_port))

        cv2.waitKey(10)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    video_capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


# Function to receive and display frames
def receive_frames():
    while True:
        data, address = receiver_socket.recvfrom(65535)

        # Convert the received data to a numpy array
        nparr = np.frombuffer(data, np.uint8)

        # Decode the numpy array into a frame
        frame = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

        # Display the frame
        cv2.imshow('Receiver', frame)

        # Break the loop if 'q' is pressed
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break


send_thread = threading.Thread(target=send_frames)
send_thread.start()

recv_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive_frames)
recv_thread.start()

send_thread.join()
recv_thread.join()

sender_socket.close()
receiver_socket.close()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The issue I am facing is that I can only see the combined feed from the webcams on one of the devices. Whenever I attempt to display the combined feed on both devices simultaneously, the program freezes.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and achieve the desired result of displaying the combined webcam feed on both devices simultaneously.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: where does it freeze

Comment: I run both the programs one after the other. And when I do that, feed from one of the devices (A) comes on the other(B) and I get a combined image on that device(B). Whenever the first frame goes to the other device(B to A), both the screen freezes. I am not getting any errors when it freezes.

Comment: I think you swapped codes in the message, but anyway... I don't think you can have two `cv2.waitKey` in two separates thread. Even less if they are supposed to capture the same keypress, as it seems (if it were working, the key press event would be captured randomly by one of the concurrent `waitKey`, not both). Besides, it makes sense only when you have a window, and one of the thread is windowless (sure, it shares memory with the one that has, so it could work, but it is unsafe when you don't know in which state that window is).

Comment: If the goal is to have the `q` key end both threads, then you should find another way. For example, terminate the thread that has the cv2 window (so `receive_thread` apparently), and then have the the main thread, after the join `receive_thread` (but before the one for `send_thread`) kill `send_thread`, or gently pass a message (a global variable `stop=True` could do) so that it ends too

Comment: please just *don't* use OpenCV for displaying the images. it's not a GUI library. use a proper GUI library.

Comment: @chrslg thanks, that makes sense regarding `waitkey`! Oh yeah, I swapped codes by mistake.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Sure, I had a time constraint, and that's why I stuck with just using OpenCV for displaying images instead of using Kivy or PyQt. Also, I would like to add that I tried the same method sometime ago and managed to send the frames back and forth. I wonder why it's not working now and I hope I didn't miss out on any crucial steps in the process.